# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, web-services

I am trying to get response of json api but I found this type of error in my code so, please help me sort out this

> Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation
>   couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start
>   with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.)
>   UserInfo=0x7fed834422c0 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start
>   with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x7fed837c2790 "Request failed: internal server
>   error (500)"}

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [params setValue:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"UID"] forKey:@"user_id"];
    [params setValue:self.strPostID forKey:@"post_id"];

    [manager POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@webservices/post/loaddetails", API_URL] parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         NSLog(@"JSON: %@", [[responseObject objectForKey:@"feed"] objectAtIndex:0]);
         NSDictionary *dict = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"feed"] objectAtIndex:0];

         if (![[dict objectForKey:@"post_image"] isEqualToString:@""])
         {
             NSArray *arrTemp = [[dict objectForKey:@"post_image"] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
             if ([[arrTemp objectAtIndex:1] isEqualToString:@"gif"])
             {

                 [controller setInitialText:@"Hi,"];
                 //[controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgViewPost.imageURL]];
                 // [controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"socialsharing-facebook-image.jpg"]];
                 [controller addImage:[UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@images/postimage/%@",API_URL,[dict objectForKey:@"post_image"]]]]];
                 [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];

             }
             else
             {

                 [controller setInitialText:@"First post from my iPhone app"];
                 //[controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgViewPost.imageURL]];
                 // [controller addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"socialsharing-facebook-image.jpg"]];
                 [controller addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@images/postimage/%@",API_URL,[dict objectForKey:@"post_image"]]]];
                 [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
             }
         }


         dict = nil;
         [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] hideProgress];
     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] hideProgress];
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:[error localizedDescription] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
         [alert show];
         alert = nil;
     }];
```

Comment: From your error message, the data returned from the webservice is not  in a correct json format. can you please post the data coming from the web service

Comment: yes i will post data

Comment: JSON: {
    feed =     (
                {
            "comment_count" = "<null>";
            "like_count" = "<null>";
            "like_type" = "<null>";
            "post_datetime" = "2015-11-14 12:02:41";
            "post_heading" = Maruti;
            "post_id" = 656;
            "post_image" = "4640321965.png";
            "post_status" = A;
            "post_type" = 0;
            "user_fname" = Kush;
            "user_id" = 38;
            "user_lname" = "Ghodasara CMT, CFP";
            "user_profile" = "7868630525.jpg";
        },

Comment: reviewing ur code.. wait

Comment: ok i am waiting thanks

Comment: Okie.. Its because of the json returning from the webservice is invalid. The json format should be in key:value format

the json format should be like this

result =     {
        a = 21;
        b = "<null>";
        c = 0;
        d = "#FFFFFF";
};

Comment: show what I change in code or json response?

Comment: try with replacing '(' with '[' and ')' with ']' next to feed =

Comment: I can not do any changes in my response so if their is any changes in code that will replace this error so tell me?

Comment: Can you show me your full coding?

Comment: when i debug above code that's time error is occures  and that code is work fine another place.